# Raspberry pi HAT id Vendor id Product origin

Tags: hat, sense-hat

I'm currently developing  a Raspberry pi HAT which I will eventually sell in the future. According to the official documentation the EEPROM memory of the HAT must contain several information. Two of this information are the Vendor Id and the Product Id.

My question is the following: Where can I get one of this number or am I free to get one 1 want? 
There is any information about it in the documentation.

Thank in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per this Pi Foundation forum [thread](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=100&t=83513)

> There will be no registry maintained for ID data. You are free to use
>   whatever data you want in the vendor fields of the "vendor info"
>   EEPROM atom (0x0001), but of course the UUID must be unique and
>   properly formatted.

Further details can be found in the [design guide](https://github.com/raspberrypi/hats/blob/master/designguide.md) and the ID EEPROM data format [spec](https://github.com/raspberrypi/hats/blob/master/eeprom-format.md), and the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/raspberrypi/hats).